# passing UDID to url

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am having trouble passing the UDID to a url in xcode:

```
[web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/?udid="+[UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier]]];
```

The above does not work. How can I fixed that?

Comment: What do you mean "does not work?"  How does it fail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The concatenation is diferent in Objective C.

DO THIS:

```
NSString *udid = [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/?udid=%@",udid];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
[web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Comment: I broke things up onto multiple lines, because one enormously long line is kinda hard to read.  +1 though :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to construct your URL string properly... "+" doesn't concatenate strings in Objective-C. Use a method like `-stringWithFormat:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do string concatenation with a "+" in Objective-C.  It should be

```
[NSURL URLWithString: [@"http://www.example.com/?udid=" stringByAppendingString: [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier]]
```